# MongoDB: Cursor isolation and transactions

Tags: mongodb

I attempt to give MongoDB a try for a new project. Never worked with it before.
The [manual on cursors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/) says:

> Because the cursor is not isolated during its lifetime, intervening
>   write operations on a document may result in a cursor that returns a
>   document more than once if that document has changed. To handle this
>   situation, see the information on snapshot mode.

That means that I always have to use **snapshot()** on read and/or **$isolated** and write operations to ensure consistent result sets or in other words, to apply some kind of transactionality. Is this correct? Or why should I not use **snapshot()** since not using it would be a risk to always get incosistent data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `snapshot()` when you are modifying the results of the `cursor` itself: while iterating the `cursor` and modifying the documents on iteration Or if you are calling a collection that you expect to be modified between calling and the iteration of the cursor itself.

also if your cursor result is larger than 1mb because you should consider using `snapshot`. [queries that have a result set of less than 1 megabyte are snapshot from default](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/)

Notice that you can't use `snapshot` if you are using `sharded collection`

Comment: As a complement: [The snapshot() does not guarantee that the data returned by the query will reflect a single moment in time nor does it provide isolation from insert or delete operations.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-isolate-cursors-from-intervening-write-operations) Unless I forgot something, there is no way to provide total isolation from concurrent insert and delete.

Comment: Ok but one cannot know how big a result is and one cannot know if the documents are modified while querying, for example: User A selects a document, user B modifies it at the same time. This could always happen, since I don't know when users access the database, so I always have to use snapshot(), don't I?

Comment: no. most of your queries are not "fetch all the collection" but fetch one or bunch - those are implicitly snapshot kind of queries .  Also if you really worry about that (which you shouldn't by the way. you want to get the most relevant document) when you retrieving the cursor, iterate it and transform it to a collection of your relevant objects and remove duplicates (by id).